# Improving the performance of the Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have few hundred thousand records to pivot dynamically.
I've tried the following query and it works fine for a selected emploeeid.

```
    declare @cols nvarchar(max)=N'',@sql nvarchar(max)=N'',@uniqcols nvarchar(max)=N''
select @cols=isnull(@cols+',','')+QUOTENAME(concat(format(FromDate,'Y'),' to ',format(ToDate,'Y'))) 
from  salaries
where EmpId=15001
print @cols

set @sql=
 'select Firstname '+@cols+'
from
(
    select e.Empid,e.Firstname,concat(format(s.FromDate,''Y''),'' to '',format(s.ToDate,''Y'')) as period,s.salary 
    from employees e join salaries s 
    on e.EmpId=s.Empid 
    where e.EmpId=15001
)as source
pivot
(
    sum(salary) for period in ('+stuff(@cols,1,1,'')+')
)as derived'
print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

QUERY PLAN:[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O7G4sETr4XteKbV2lYo7Ph2DaMty6943/view?usp=sharing]

and when i want to pivot all the records of the employees, it is executing a very long time. Is it the right way to do or any better way to do?
How do i retrieve the pivot in a short time?

```
    declare @cols nvarchar(max)=N'',@sql nvarchar(max)=N'',@uniqcols nvarchar(max)=N''
select @cols=isnull(@cols+',','')+QUOTENAME(concat(format(FromDate,'Y'),' to ',format(ToDate,'Y'))) 
from  salaries
print @cols

set @sql=
 'select Firstname '+@cols+'
from
(
    select e.Empid,e.Firstname,concat(format(s.FromDate,''Y''),'' to '',format(s.ToDate,''Y'')) as period,s.salary 
    from employees e join salaries s 
    on e.EmpId=s.Empid 
)as source
pivot
(
    sum(salary) for period in ('+stuff(@cols,1,1,'')+')
)as derived'
print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: How long is very long? You should at least include the picture of the query plan

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VPkzK7AppAbLlJRKiGRYgt8KVZ0TSxf9/view?usp=sharing] for the pivot which is filtered by the employee id.  and i didn't get a query plan for the other as i cancelled the execution after half-an-hour because it is still executing.

Comment: You can get estimated plan using the printed SQL text

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uXap8Ng-YEa7Aa3iEDnFnikWTm5uDEEN/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: That's the SQL generation part, not from the printed SQL

Comment: As i am a beginner i haven't  used  query plan stuff and i don't know about the printed SQL

Comment: I mean the one that you print in your SQL before you execute it: `print @sql` -- since that's now the actual SQL that will be executed with `sp_executesql` -- which of course doesn't finish, but you should get the printout, at least if you comment out the execution.

Comment: Thank you @James,  I have made a minor changes in converting date and here's the printed SQL for  `print @sql` [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uXap8Ng-YEa7Aa3iEDnFnikWTm5uDEEN/view?usp=sharing]